# How to create customer in stripe payment gateway flutter?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am using stripe sdk for payment and trying to create customer in that ,

```
static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createcustomer() async {

    try {
    var body = {
        'name': 'Jenny Rosen',
        'address': {
          'line1': '510 Townsend St',
          'postal_code': '98140',
          'city': 'San Francisco',
          'state': 'CA',
          'country': 'US',
        }
      };
      var response = await http.post(
         'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers',
          body: json.encode(body),
          headers: StripeService.headers
      );
      print('resvfdg: ${jsonDecode(response.body)}');
      return jsonDecode(response.body);

    } catch (err) {
      print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
    }
    return null;
  }
```

i am getting the error `code: parameter_unknown,message: Received unknown parameter` ,
how to create customer in stripe ?? or what i am missing in this ?
i don't know how to apply this and i need to create customer for doing international payment outside india , if i done payment in "INR" it will working properly , but for any other currency they asked for name and address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dio, this code is working for me:

```
static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createcustomer() async {
  try {
    var data = {
      'name': 'Jenny Rosen',
      'address': {
        'line1': '510 Townsend St',
        'postal_code': '98140',
        'city': 'San Francisco',
        'state': 'CA',
        'country': 'US',
      }
    };
    Response response = await Dio().post('https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers',
      data: data,
      options: Options(contentType:Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType,
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ${secret}', // your secret key
          }
      ),
    );
    print('response: ${jsonDecode(response.data)}');
    return jsonDecode(response.data);

  } catch (err) {
    print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this api is working fine but response is paramter unknown
{error: {code: parameter_unknown, doc_url: https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown, message: Received unknown parameter: {"address":"sss","email":"aryan@gmail.com","name":"aryan","phone":"953667"}, param: {"address":"sss","email":"aryan@gmail.com","name":"aryan","phone":"953667"}, type: invalid_request_error}}
**Flutter Code**

```
Future createcustomer() async {
try {
  var body = {
    "address": "sss",
    "email": "aryan@gmail.com",
    "name": "aryan",
    "phone": "95366710",
  };


  //final response  = await http.post(Uri.parse("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers"),
 final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers"),
 headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Authorization": "Bearer ${sKey}",
    },
    body: json.encode(body),
  );
  print('resvfdg: ${jsonDecode(response.body)}');
  return jsonDecode(response.body);


} catch (err) {
  print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
}
```

}